# Distinguish between Null and empty collections in WebParam

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, cxf

```
@WebService
public interface MyService {
  public void doStuff( @WebParam(name = "someObjectList") List<SomeObject> someObjectList);
}
```

I want to distinguish between null and empty list. How should I annotate `@WebParam someObjectList`?

It should be possible, I found this [JAXB example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxb-representing-null-and-empty.html).

I'm generating ws with apache cxf 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most logic way to do this is to:

```
public class MyListParameter {

 @XmlElementWrapper(nillable=true)
 public List<MyObject> myObjects;

}
```

and then:

```
@WebService
public interface MyService {
  public void doStuff( @WebParam(name = "someObjectList") MyListParameter someObjectList);
}
```